# Create an event listener triggered by CPU load percentage

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, event-listener, cpu-load

In Task Manager, you can see your CPU load.

[image]

I'm trying to create a script that sends an email if the CPU consistently stays above 80% for X minutes.

Apparently you can get the CPU load in PowerShell by running this command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor |
    Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average |
    Select Average
```

This solution is not great because I'd have to take samples of the CPU every couple seconds and use a counter.

Is there a way to add an event listener to CPU load?

Something like

```
# Triggered by an event listener
if (cpu.load >= 80% for 3 minutes) { // Send Email }
```

Comment: You don't have any monitoring services as is, such as SCOM?  Best not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Agree with @TheIncorrigible1 but if you must roll-your-own, take a look at `Get-Counter`. https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/02/07/performance-counters-in-powershell.aspx & https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-day-to-day-admin-tasks-monitoring-performance/ should help get you started